Are block rewards ordered deterministically?
I noticed differing ordering of block rewards when making calls to getBlock via different node providers, as well as comparing to web-based block explorers. One block explorer (bitquery io) simply ordered by pubkey.
So it seems plausible that block rewards are not ordered deterministically. Can anyone confirm this?
